# Unexpected text "return" inside function

Tags: flutter

```
int FriendsNum() {
  _firestore.collection('Friends').doc(User.userID).collection("Friends").where("Status",isEqualTo: 2)
      .get()
      .then((res)=> return{res.size});
  return 0;
}
```

I am basically trying to get the number of documents that are inside the collection that has the status of 2, and the value should be returned so it can be displayed for the user, what can be changed in the syntax to make this work? with many thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `return res.size`?

Comment: yes @DarkMath  I tried it as well

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your function return type to a [Future](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await) and use the `await` keyword to get the result from the firestore collection as it is an asynchronous operation itself.

The updated code will be the following:

```dart
Future<int> FriendsNum() async {
 final count = await _firestore
      .collection('Friends')
      .doc(User.userID)
      .collection("Friends")
      .where("Status",isEqualTo: 2)
      .get()
      .then((res) => res.size); 
  return count;
}
```

Comment: I see, but how can I fix  method 'map' isn't defined for the type 'Future' in this particular example?

Comment: It is updated. You can use `then` instead.

Comment: tried it, it does not return the value of the counted status = 2 in the document , it returns an instance of 'Future<int>'

Comment: You have to await the function call to the value. For more detail please look at the link I attached in the answer.